# Change the column affected by update via PreparedStatement

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I have this code here:

```
private void updateGame(String column, String player, String block, String state) {
        try {
            Connection conn = db.openConnection();
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE games SET ? = ? WHERE game_id = ?");
            ps.setString(1, column);
            ps.setString(2, block);
            ps.setInt(3, getGameId(state, player));
            ps.executeUpdate();
            conn.close();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
        }
    }
```

When I pass in the **column** parameter, I want it to update a specific column in the database that I wrote when calling the function. I have multiple columns that are similar and that's why I am using this method. However, when I do it this way, it just gives out an error. I tried setting the column directly, without a question mark **(?)**, and it worked.  Not a duplicate because of the reply i got that is a different solution to the one in the "duplicate"

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: I want to change the column I update by passing it when calling the function. However, I can't set it by using "?". I can only set a single column by directly writing it in the statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately you can only bind column values to a `PreparedStatement`, not column names.

You could instead use a formatter to perform the substitution:

```
MessageFormat.format("UPDATE games SET {0} = ? WHERE game_id = ?", column)
```

Comment: I guess this can lead to a SQL injection!

Answer (score 0):

Because of (pre)compiling the statement (where all the given tables and columns are involved), you may not bind column names.